# Secure serving of images in combination with using ImageResizer

Tags: authorization, asp.net-mvc-4, imageresizer

[This is a followup / cleaned question regarding earlier discussion here with Computer Linguist, hope i specified this enough]
Can ImageResizer grab files outside site root and serve them(Thus avoiding making the unaltered originals available online)?
Or what is the best practise for this scenario?

*Should the originals be stored outside site root, a base-resized image be stored online(protected via url auth / httpmodule etc) and then let Imageresizer do on the fly resizing for thumbs etc based on that image? As far as ive seen i havent found a way to restrict access 100% to a folder except for when requested via imageresizer. If ImageResizer can resize, user can access it seems sofar.

*Or is perhaps a solution with a controller serving the original image then handled by ImageResizer.

The key purpose to:

1. Be able to customize permission rules completely
2. Be able to serve in a secure fashion (atleast so far as i have learned unaltered user-uploaded images should not be accessible directly under siteroot). And preserving originals seems like a future-proof strategy.
3. Be able to utilize the awesomeness of ImageResizer on-the-fly resizing.

Any input on how others have implemented this is appreciated as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Locating the files outside the site root doesn't accomplish anything. You'll still have to mount them as a virtual folder, making them accessible again.
2. MVC is written in such a way that it will be absolutely useless here - it procrastinates until ProcessRequest to do anything.
3. ImageResizer is quite irrelevant to this question - it behaves likes StaticFileHandler for your purposes - you need a generic authorization system.
4. [ASP.NET URL Authorization](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/wce3kxhd%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) sounds like it may not be sophisticated enough for your desired level of complexity.

To accomplish custom authorization logic, you will need to handle the AuthorizeRequest event in the HTTP pipeline and implement your path parsing logic from scratch. You can handle the event in Global.asax.cs or by implementing IHttpModule.

In AuthorizeRequest, you can access the incoming path and querystring data before ImageResizer or any other HttpModule or HttpHandler ever sees it, decide whether or not the user should be able to access it today, and either let the request continue or throw an HTTP 401 error.

I suggest using ILSpy to look at the UrlAuthorizationModule found in System.Web.Security. It's only a couple pages of code in length, and pretty straightforward.

Comment: I looked a bit at AuthorizeRequest earlier and built a clean httpmodule to set my permission structure on. The thing i really couldnt wrap my head against was how to best handle source images seen to xss and other stuff.
BUT i was leaning on forcing a re-encode on all uploads without changing height/width and so forth(i think i saw you mentioning it in some of your docs) and use that as the fullsize base image. Anyway, togheter with extension, size, format checks on upload this would perhaps give a decent level of safety. Unsure if putting the files in a virtul folder would give any benefits.

Comment: On thing i thought about though that you mentioned briefly earlier regarding disk cache. The imagecache seems to have a web.config rule preventing access to it. This should mean that as long as i protect the originals, ImageResizer wont serve the cached verions, correct? Or would i have to implement authorization on ImageResizer event as well?

Comment: As long as you protect the originals, ImageResizer will protect the variations. Never use the filename or extension provided with an upload. Use a GUID and your detected format extension. This will prevent the server and client from attempting to interpret the uploaded data except as a static image. If you're really paranoid, just re-encode the original during upload.

Comment: Do make sure to take 'fakeExtensions' into account or disable them. I.e, image.jpg.ashx and image.jpg are 2 ways of accessing the same file. And don't use the FolderResizeSyntax or ImageHandlerSyntax plugins, since they perform rewrites *after* your authorization code runs. Or, if you want to support post-authorize rewrites and fake extensions, make a public method that checks path/query/user and call it from Config.Current.Pipeline.AuthorizeImage (which is fired after all rewriting is finished). UrlAuthorization is checked at that stage as well.

Comment: As my plan is atm the permission structure will be based only on parent folder(structured after the username / area / date), not for specific files. So the filenames wont matter into the evaluation. The mainpoint is a per user permission customization, not for individual files at this time.

Im setting either static names for the images or random like guid or such. Then i will probably store the sanitized original imagename in the database along with the path, but hasent gotten to that yet.

Comment: Regarding the input my plan was something like the below code:
`var settings = new ResizeSettings("process=always&format=jpg&quality=92");
var Processed = new ImageJob(InBytes, string.Concat(TargetPath, FileName), settings);
Processed.AddFileExtension = true;
Processed.CreateParentDirectory = true;
Processed.Build();`
FileName is a string set by me that dont contain any extension. Not the final product but this seems to work fine sofar and should reencode all incoming files as jpeg? Other areas will perhaps allow keeping of other imagetypes aswell. But thats another matter.